# decrypt pgp files from a folder and moving it - c#

Tags: c#, encryption, bouncycastle, public-key-encryption, pgp

I am trying to decrypt `.pgp` files from a location and then moving those files to another location. I looked into this [article](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/PGP-Encryption--Decryption-in-C-1994.php) and code accordingly. In my code I am developing an application which will check to a certain location after every 100 seconds and if there are files then it will decrypt and move. but I am getting this exception `The process cannot access the file 'c:\file.pgp' because it is being used by another process.`

Here is my code where I am calling that class which I copied from that article.

```
private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do the stuff you want to be done every hour;
        string sourcePath = @"files location";
        string archivePath = @"move original file after decrypting location";
        string targetPath = @"decrypted file location";
        string pubkeyPath = @"public key location\PGPPublicKey.txt";
        string privkeyPath = @"private key location\PGPPrivateKey.txt";

        string fileName = "";
        string destFile = "";

        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
        {
            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);

            // Copy the files and overwrite destination files if they already exist.
            foreach (string s in files)
            {
                PGPDecrypt test = new PGPDecrypt(s,
                                         privkeyPath,
                                         "password",
                                         targetPath + "decrypted.txt",
                                         pubkeyPath);
                FileStream fs = File.Open(s, FileMode.Open);
                test.decrypt(fs, targetPath + "decrypted.txt");

                // Use static Path methods to extract only the file name from the path.
                fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);
                destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(archivePath, fileName);
                System.IO.File.Move(s, archivePath);
            }
        }        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is I ended up and it is working

```
//Decrypt
using DidiSoft.Pgp;
 PGPLib pgp = new PGPLib();

            string inputFileLocation = file Location; 
            string privateKeyLocation = @"I posted my private at this location";
            string privateKeyPassword = "Decryption Password";
            string outputFile = @"Output Location";

            // decrypt and obtain the original file name
            // of the decrypted file
            string originalFileName =
              pgp.DecryptFile(inputFileLocation,
                          privateKeyLocation,
                          privateKeyPassword,
                          outputFile);
//Move decrypted file to archive
string path = Decrypted file Location;
            string path2 = @"Archive file location" + Path.GetFileName(file); ;
            try
            {
                if (!File.Exists(path))
                {
                    // This statement ensures that the file is created,
                    // but the handle is not kept.
                    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path)) { }
                }

                // Ensure that the target does not exist.
                if (File.Exists(path2))
                    File.Delete(path2);

                // Move the file.
                File.Move(path, path2);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Where are you getting the error. If you are getting error while moving it might be because your filestream is not close. After decryption and before move close the filestream with fs.Close();

Comment: I am getting the exception on this line `FileStream fs = File.Open(s, FileMode.Open);`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue you are having is caused by the file not being closed, when you loop with the foreach loop the first iteration probably works. However, the next time, because it was never closed, it is still being used.

Try adding

```
fs.Close();
```

At the end of the foreach loop

Comment: `fs.Close()` didn't work because I am getting this exception on `FileStream fs = File.Open(s, FileMode.Open);`

Comment: You might need to also add `FileClose();` before `fs.Close();`

Comment: there is not file to close before